# MySQL syntax error (Error 1064) on Trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a trigger that when the field TEMPO_PERCORSO (VARCHAR) IS UPDATED retrieve the information relevant to minute and second, transform into second add then the cent and store in the field PUNTEGGIO  this is the instruction

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdPunteggioTrig
   AFTER UPDATE ON t_risultati_manche
    FOR EACH row
    BEGIN    
    DECLARE MIN INT;
    DECLARE SEC INT;
    DECLARE CENT VARCHAR(2)   
      DECLARE PUNTSTR VARCHAR(10)
      IF (LENGTH(NEW.TEMPO_PERCORSO))>1 THEN
        SET MIN = CONVERT(SUBSTRING(NEW.TEMPO_PERCORSO, 1, 2), SIGNED INTEGER) * 60;
        SET SEC = CONVERT(SUBSTRING(NEW.TEMPO_PERCORSO, 4, 2), SIGNED INTEGER);
        SET PUNINT = MIN + SEC + NEW.PENALITA;
        SET CEN = SUBSTRING(NEW.TEMPO_PERCORSO, -2);
        SET PUNTSTR = CONCAT(CONVERT(PUNTINT,char), '.', CENT);
        SET NEW.PUNTEGGIO = CONVERT(PUNTSTR, DECIMAL(7, 2));
      END IF;
END;
```

this is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: looks like you are missing the delimiter. At the start `delimiter //` and at the end `end;//`

Comment: I've tried to add the delimiter but nothing changed it seems that there is something wrong with the second and third Declaration, it's marched as row with error and it's reported as declare is not a valid input at this position and then again another error on the END iF (as avove not a valid input at this position)and on the END (expected end of statement